# String concatenation does not work in Bash cygwin

Tags: string, bash, variables, cygwin, concatenation

Tell me this, why this code does not work in Cygwin ?
I've tried use **\.** and different symbol combinations between variable.
Scopes tried too ( round, figure ).
Dunno what up.

My code is here and it WORKS !!!: **http://ideone.com/0tLmzu**

NOTE: I just trying to concatenate two strings in one, but Cygwin can't do that.
Example below:

`echo $a$b prints only $b, not $a and $b`

Comment: your question is not clear at all. What is the problem?

Comment: When you say "Hurry up, guys ! I really need help... I f*cked up", you will offend a lot of people who might otherwise be willing to offer assistance.  If you made a mistake it's not our problem, so please be careful how you phrase your question.  We are not your servants.

Comment: It's not offence, It's just my nerves )))

Comment: If you don't, just ignore it

Answer (score 7):

I believe I know what this is.  The file is a dos file and not unix.  If you use vim you can:

```
vim file
:set ff=unix
:x
```

Or if you do not want to use vim, this from the command line:

```
dos2unix file
```

Comment: @cforbish Could you explain your reasoning a little more? I'd like to know the thought process that led you to this answer.

Comment: @Samveen It is because the differences in the breakline characters used in Windows and Unix, which are encoded differently.

Comment: @Dan I was more interested in the thought process that led to his answer(the question gave me nothing). I understand the `CR` vs `CRLF` difference well enough :).